# Hibernate - Object Is Not An Instance Of Declaring Class

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a very simple entity:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "Message")
public class MessageEntity {

    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

The *persistence.xml* contains `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop`, so the tables are created correctly based on the annotations. Still, when I persist the entity, I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of org.acme.project.MessageEntity.id
at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:192) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4746) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4465) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:511) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:116) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
... 154 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:169) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
... 165 more
```

Or when field is annotated instead of the getter:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of org.acme.project.MessageEntity.id
at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:60) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4746) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4465) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:511) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:116) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
... 154 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field org.acme.project.MessageEntity.id to org.acme.project.MessageEntity
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:387) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:57) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
... 165 more
```

The code producing the exceptions is very complicated, so take a moment to really get it:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public void doMagic() {
    this.em.persist(new MessageEntity());
}
```

It's probably a small and very stupid mistake that makes Hibernate think it should set the ID to `MessageEntity`, but I can't seem to find where it is. What's the problem?

Comment: Show us the complete code of the entity, and the code causing that exception to be thrown.

Comment: @JBNizet I added the getter and setter.

Comment: You completely changed the code, which had several other fields, a comment about the builder pattern, and a SequenceGenerator. Are you  still getting the same exception with the above entity, containing a single id field and an identity generator?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, I do. The other fields don't matter, the builder pattern does not matter, and neither does how I define the sequence. Putting working entities into this project will make them fail with similar exceptions.

Comment: Please post the import statements of your entity. Although I don't think it's the problem, I'd also remove the Table annotation, which is useless.

Comment: @JBNizet I added the import, and now I believe the problem is somewhere *entirely* different.

Comment: Can't really see anything wrong here, but could you try to remove the name attribute of `@Entity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this exception was nowhere near the cause of the problem. I had a WAR inside an EAR, and the WAR had duplicates of the libraries inside the EAR. So there probably was a `ClassCastException` or something internally, because the objects of the WAR could not be used by the beans inside the EAR.